# Change current row color with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a form control button in excel to change the color of that entire row and be able to duplicate that button on following rows but only have the button action affect the row corresponding to said button. Current Macro is:

```
    Sub RED()
    Rows("3:3").Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 10066431
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End Sub
```

This works fine for the first button, but when I try to duplicate (pull down more buttons) they all only affect the row stated in the original code (3:3) I can't figure out a way, if there is one, to select current row as opposed to the defined row 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Form Control CommandButtons are properly aligned with Rows, place the following two macros on a Standard Module like Module1.

```
Sub RED(iRow As Long)
With Rows(iRow).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 10066431
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub

Sub ColorRow()
Dim r As Long
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
r = shp.TopLeftCell.Row
Call RED(r)
End Sub
```

Now assign the macro ColorRow to all the CommnadButtons. So when you click a CommandButton the code will color the row which the CommandButton is aligned to.